# Python (Flask) Session variables not being set

Tags: python, flask

I have this code:

````
sD = await db.session.getChatbotDetails(request.json.get("apiKey"))
if sD:
   setSessionDetails(sD.get_json(), request.json.get("apiKey"))```
````

and then:

```
def setSessionDetails(sD, api_key):
    session["company_name"] = sD["company_name"]
    session["api_key"] = api_key
    session["website_url"] = sD["website_url"]
    session["welcome_prompt"] = sD["welcome_prompt"]
```

but then when I log for example

```
@app.route("/chat", methods=["POST"])
async def chat():
    print(session)
    if isAuth(request.json.get("apiKey"), "https://website_url") == 200:
```

but `session` returns `<SecureCookieSession {}>`... so why isn't it storing the session values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to be aware of when using `session` is that Flask stores that information using cookies and as it says in the [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/quickstart/#sessions):

> A note on cookie-based sessions: Flask will take the values you put into the session object and serialize them into a cookie. If you are finding some values do not persist across requests, cookies are indeed enabled, and you are not getting a clear error message, check the size of the cookie in your page responses compared to the size supported by web browsers.

I doubt this is the case if you are only storing that information in session. But worth checking if you are storing a lot of information.

---

Another possibility is that, you didn't mention how are you making requests to Flask. Like I said in the previous point, session uses cookie to store information and read from it. If you aren't persisting cookies between requests then `session` is going to be empty as you are seeing.

For example lets say you have this `app.py`

```py
from flask import Flask, session

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = b"A SECRET"


@app.route("/")
def index():
    session["company_name"] = "A company name"
    session["api_key"] = "An API key"
    session["website_url"] = "https://example.com/business"
    session["welcome_prompt"] = "Welcome!"
    return "Stored cookies"


@app.route("/cookies")
def read_cookies():
    return str(session)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

If we use curl to query Flask without storing cookies between requests, when calling `/cookies` endpoint then it should be empty.

```bash
$ curl http://localhost:5000/
Stored cookies
$ curl http://localhost:5000/cookies
<SecureCookieSession {}>
```

Now we should try to store cookies and read cookies between requests.

```bash
# Store cookies in a file named 'flask-cookies'

$ curl -c flask-cookies http://localhost:5000/
Stored cookies
$ curl -b flask-cookies http://localhost:5000/cookies
<SecureCookieSession {'api_key': 'An API key', 'company_name': 'A company name',
 'website_url': 'https://example.com/business', 'welcome_prompt': 'Welcome!'}>
```